# strchr in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

I'm trying to write the equivalent of strchr, but with NSStrings... I've currently got this:

```
Boolean nsstrchr(NSString* s, char c)
{
    NSString *tmps = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", c];
    NSCharacterSet *cSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: tmps];
    NSRange rg = [s rangeOfCharacterFromSet: cSet];
    return rg.location != NSNotFound;
}
```

This seems needlessly complex... Is there a way to do this (preferably, one that doesn't involve turning the NSString into a cstring which doubles the run time, or writing it myself using characterAtIndex:...  Am I missing some obvious method in the NSString description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KennyTM has already noted (in a comment) that you can use `-[NSString rangeOfString:]` instead of `-[NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet]`. I don't mean to steal his helpful answer, but I wanted to point out that you can wrap this up in a category on `NSString` to make it easier to use:

```
@interface NSString (AdditionalStringOps)
- (BOOL) containsCharacter:(char) c;
@end

@implementation NSString (AdditionalStringOps)

- (BOOL) containsCharacter:(char) c
{
    NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
    return [self rangeOfString:tmp].location != NSNotFound;
}

@end
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
if ([myString containsCharacter:'A']) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: @OP: Also note the use of `BOOL` instead of `Boolean` for Objective-C (soz, pedantics).

Answer (score 0):

As @KennyTM mentioned, use `rangeOfString:`.  If you really have to deal with stuff on the `char` level, you can pull out the `char*` via `-UTF8String` (or `-cStringUsingEncoding:`) and then search for your character in there like you would on any other `char*` (probably by using `strchr`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean nsstrchr(NSString* s, char c)
{
    NSString *tmps = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", c];
    NSRange rg = [s rangeOfString: tmps];
    return rg.location != NSNotFound;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several simplifications.

1. Use `[s rangeOfString:tmps]` to eliminate the character set.
2. The character set can be created with `[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange(c, 1)]`, so you don't need to create `tmps`
3. `strchr([s UTF8String], c)` — assuming `c` is an ASCII character, and the returned pointer won't escape the function (there's a risk the pointer becomes dangling).